# How to access Workitem Fields in azure devops (Like Development ,deployment,link fields)

Tags: azure-devops

Can anybody tell me how to GET the fields associated to workitem 
Like Development field in azure devops.

[image: How to fetch this data through any rest API,powershell ???]

OR

How to fetch the links associated to workitems in azure devops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [Work item rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/Work%20Items/Get%20Work%20Item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#workitemexpand) to get the links associated to workitems by adding the **`$expand=relations** to the api string..

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?`$expand=relations&api-version=5.0
```

You can check below example in powershell script.

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/<Org>/<Proj>/_apis/wit/workitems/5?`$expand=All&api-version=5.0"

$connectionToken = "<PAT>"

$base64AuthInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method get
```

Then you can get the associated linked in the `relations` property.
[image]

Comment: There are some list of queries in which each has a work item
In each work item there will be a development tab.
In that there will be list of links associated to that particular work item .

How to fetch those links???

Comment: Could you describe your scenario in details? Donot really understand the question 'How to fetch those links'.

Comment: In azure Devops ,in your organization , go to queries > shared queries>...
in this shared queries ,there will be list of ID's ,Editors,charts etc tabs.
for each workitem ID there will be a related work tab or development tab.


after association a workitem to a commit ,there generates a link in development link.

so i want to fetch the list of links associated to that particular workitem .

how to do that???

Comment: There is no direct way to fetch these links. You may need to call rest api to get them, Above powershell scripts is the example how to fetch the related workitem links using restful api.